# How to disable a spring logger?

Tags: java, spring, logging, log4j, log4j2

I'd like to disable `org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler` logging with `log4j / log4j2`.

I tried the following which did not work:

```
<loggers>
    <logger name="log4j.logger.org.springframework.integration" level="off" />
</loggers>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove `log4j.logger` from the logger name.

```
<loggers>
    <logger name="org.springframework.integration">
       <level value="off" />
    </logger>
</loggers>
```

Comment: Great, glad I could help! The log4j.logger thing is a how loggers were named in the old properties config way.  You don't need to do that anymore in XML.

Comment: @gregwhitaker Do you know how to achieve this with log4j2 ? Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a typo (extra "s"), try:

```
<logger>
    <logger name="log4j.logger.org.springframework.integration" level="off" />
</logger>
```

You can also try:

```
<logger name="log4j.logger.org.springframework.integration">
 <level value="OFF"/>
</logger>
```

Comment: Yes it was just a type here, not in my code. I tried both solutions but none of them worked...